# React-Table not updating after data prop is changed from state

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-table

I have a react table in which the data prop is set through response data from an axios call into state. I make some changes through a modal and call the same axios call to update the state, which it does great, but the UI for react table does not update. I have added the entire class. It is the front end for a laravel application and have checked the return on the axios call and everything if fine. It even updates the state of the class correctly.

Please see below for the entire class. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactTable from 'react-table'
import 'react-table/react-table.css'
import axios from 'axios';
import Modal from 'react-modal';
import EditableLabel from 'react-inline-editing';
import Select from 'react-select'

const headers = {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')
}

const customStyles = {
    content : {
      top                   : '50%',
      left                  : '50%',
      right                 : 'auto',
      bottom                : 'auto',
      marginRight           : '-50%',
      transform             : 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
      maxHeight:'800px',
      backgroundColor:'#004167',
      borderRadius: '5px',
      minWidth:'600px',
      maxWidth:'600px',
      position: 'absolute',
    }
  };

  const colourStyles = {
    singleValue: styles => ({ ...styles, fontSize: '18px' }),
//   control: styles => ({ ...styles, height: '20px' })
  }



export default class Users extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
          users:[],
          modalIsOpen:false,
          confirmPass:'',
          originalPass:'',
          saveDisable:false,
          errors:'',
          webErrors:'',
          addModalIsOpen:false,
          addUserRole: 0,
          newPass:'',
          confirmNewPass:'',
          addErrors:'',
          addSaveDisable:false,
          newUserEmail: 'user@user.com',
          addUserFirstName: 'First Name',
          addUserLastName: 'Last Name',
          instructors:[
            { value: -1, label: 'None' }
            ],
          studentSelected:false,
          addUserInstructor: -1
        };
      }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getUsers()
    }

    getUsers = () =>{
        axios.get('/all-users').then(response => {

            this.setState({ 
              users: response.data, 
            })
          })
    }

    getParent = () =>{
        return document.querySelector('.course_builder_wrapper');
    }

    closeModal(){
        this.setState({modalIsOpen:false, confirmPass:'', originalPass:'', errors:'',saveDisable:false});
    }

    _handleFocusOutFirstName = (text) =>{
        this.setState({userFirstName:text})
    }

    _handleFocusOutLastName = (text) =>{
        this.setState({userLastName:text})
    }

    _handleFocusOutAddFirstName = (text) =>{
        this.setState({addUserFirstName:text})
    }

     _handleFocusOutAddLastName = (text) =>{
        this.setState({addUserLastName:text})
    }

    selectChange = (value) =>{
        this.setState({userRole:value.value})
    }

    addUserSelectChange = (value) =>{
        this.setState({addUserRole:value.value})
        if(value.value == 3){
            this.setState({studentSelected:true})
            this.getInstructors()
        }else{
            this.setState({studentSelected:false})
        }
    }

    instructorSelectChange = (value) =>{
        this.setState({addUserInstructor:value.value})
    }

    saveUser = () =>{

        var curr = this

        const vals ={
            user_id:this.state.activeUser.id,
            role_id:this.state.userRole,
            first_name: this.state.userFirstName,
            last_name: this.state.userLastName,
            email: this.state.email,
            pass: this.state.originalPass != '' ? this.state.originalPass : ''
        }

        axios
            .post('/update-user', vals, headers)
            .then(function (response) {

                const data = response.data
                curr.closeModal()
                curr.getUsers()

            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
                curr.setState({webErrors: error})
            })

    }

    addUser = () =>{
        if(this.state.newPass != ''){

            var curr = this

            const vals ={
                role_id:this.state.addUserRole,
                first_name: this.state.addUserFirstName,
                last_name: this.state.addUserLastName,
                email: this.state.newUserEmail,
                pass: this.state.newPass,
                instructor: this.state.addUserInstructor
            }

             axios
            .post('/add-user', vals, headers)
            .then(function (response) {

                const data = response.data
                curr.closeAddUserModal()
                curr.getUsers()

            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
                curr.setState({webErrors: error})
            })

        }else{
            this.setState({addErrors:'Please Enter A Password'})
        }
    }

    confirmPassCheck = (event) =>{
        this.setState(
            {confirmPass:event.target.value},
            () => this.matchPasswords()
            );
    }

    originalPassChange = (event) =>{
        this.setState(
            {originalPass:event.target.value},
             () => this.matchPasswords()
            );
    }

    newPassSet = (event) =>{
        this.setState(
            {newPass:event.target.value},
             () => this.matchNewPasswords()
            );
    }

    confirmNewPassCheck = (event) =>{
        this.setState(
            {confirmNewPass:event.target.value},
            () => this.matchNewPasswords()
            );
    }

    matchPasswords = () =>{
        if(this.state.originalPass == this.state.confirmPass){
            this.setState({saveDisable:false, errors:''})
        }else{
            this.setState({saveDisable:true, errors:'Passwords Do Not Match'})
        }
    }

    matchNewPasswords = () =>{
        if(this.state.newPass == this.state.confirmNewPass){
            this.setState({addSaveDisable:false, addErrors:''})
        }else{
            this.setState({addSaveDisable:true, addErrors:'Passwords Do Not Match'})
        }
    }

    changeEmail = (text) =>{
        this.setState({email:text})
    }

    changeAddEmail = (text) =>{
        this.setState({newUserEmail:text})
    }

    openAddUserModal = () =>{
        this.setState({addModalIsOpen:true})
    }

    closeAddUserModal = () =>{
        this.setState({addModalIsOpen:false}) 
    }

    getInstructors = () =>{
        axios.get('/all-instructors-select').then(response => {
            this.setState({ 
              instructors: response.data, 
            })
          })
    }


    render() {

        const users = this.state.users
        const options = [
            { value: 1, label: 'Admin' },
            { value: 2, label: 'Instructor' },
            { value: 3, label: 'Student' },
            { value: 4, label: 'Contributor' }
        ]

        return (
            <div className="users_wrap">
                <h4>Users</h4>
                <div className="add_user_b">
                    <button className="add_user_button" onClick={this.openAddUserModal}>Add User</button>
                </div>
                {users.length > 0 &&
                <div className="user_table">
                    <ReactTable
                        data={users}
                        NoDataComponent={() => null}
                        defaultPageSize={users.length}
                        showPagination={false}
                        columns={[
                            {
                                Header: 'First Name',
                                accessor: 'first_name'
                            },
                            {
                                Header: 'Last Name',
                                accessor: 'last_name'
                            },
                            {
                                Header: 'Role',
                                accessor: 'roles[0].name'
                            }
                        ]}
                        getTdProps={(state, rowInfo, column, instance) => {

                          return {
                            onClick: (e, handleOriginal) => {
                                const activeItem = rowInfo.original;
                                this.setState({activeUser:activeItem, modalIsOpen:true, userFirstName:activeItem.first_name, userLastName:activeItem.last_name, userRole: activeItem.roles[0].id, email:activeItem.email})
                            }
                          };
                        }}
                    />
                    </div>
                }
                <Modal
                        isOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen}
                        onAfterOpen={this.afterOpenModal}
                        onRequestClose={this.closeModal}
                        style={customStyles}
                        shouldCloseOnOverlayClick={false}
                        parentSelector={this.getParent}
                >
                    <div>
                        <div className="modal_header">Edit User</div>
                        <div className="modal_inner_mat">
                            {this.state.activeUser != undefined &&
                            <div>
                            <div className="modal_grid_3">
                                <div className="modal_grid_item">
                                    <EditableLabel text={this.state.activeUser.first_name}
                                        labelClassName='modal_label'
                                        inputClassName='modal_input'
                                        inputWidth='150px'
                                        inputHeight='28px'
                                        inputMaxLength='50'
                                        onFocus={this._handleFocus}
                                        onFocusOut={this._handleFocusOutFirstName}
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <div className="modal_grid_item">
                                    <EditableLabel text={this.state.activeUser.last_name}
                                        labelClassName='modal_label'
                                        inputClassName='modal_input'
                                        inputWidth='150px'
                                        inputHeight='28px'
                                        inputMaxLength='50'
                                        onFocus={this._handleFocus}
                                        onFocusOut={this._handleFocusOutLastName}
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <div className="modal_grid_item">
                                    <Select 
                                    options={options} 
                                    defaultValue={{value: this.state.activeUser.roles[0].id, label: this.state.activeUser.roles[0].name}}
                                    styles={colourStyles}
                                    onChange={this.selectChange}
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <div className="modal_input_label">
                                    First Name
                                </div>
                                <div className="modal_input_label">
                                    Last Name
                                </div>
                                <div className="modal_input_label">
                                    Role
                                </div>
                            </div>
                             <div className="modal_grid_email">

                                <div className="modal_grid_item">
                                    <EditableLabel text={this.state.activeUser.email}
                                        labelClassName='modal_label'
                                        inputClassName='modal_input'
                                        inputWidth='350px'
                                        inputHeight='28px'
                                        inputMaxLength='50'
                                        onFocus={this._handleFocus}
                                        onFocusOut={this.changeEmail}
                                    />
                                </div>
                                 <div className="modal_input_label">
                                    Email
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <h5>Reset Password</h5>
                            <div className="modal_grid_2 pass_grid">

                                <div className="modal_grid_item">
                                   <input type="password" className="pass_input" onChange={this.originalPassChange}/>
                                </div>
                                <div className="modal_grid_item">
                                   <input type="password" className="pass_input" onChange={this.confirmPassCheck}/>
                                </div>
                                 <div className="modal_input_label">
                                    Password
                                </div>
                                 <div className="modal_input_label">
                                    Confirm Password
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            </div>
                            }
                        </div>
                        <div className="modal_button_wrap">
                            <button className="cancel_button" onClick={() => this.closeModal()}>Cancel</button>
                            <button disabled={this.state.saveDisable} className="save_button" onClick={() => this.saveUser()}>Save</button>
                            <div className="error_msg">{this.state.errors}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </Modal>
                <Modal
                        isOpen={this.state.addModalIsOpen}
                        onAfterOpen={this.afterOpenModal}
                        onRequestClose={this.closeModal}
                        style={customStyles}
                        shouldCloseOnOverlayClick={false}
                        parentSelector={this.getParent}
                >
                    <div>
                        <div className="modal_header">Add User</div>
                        <div className="modal_inner_mat">
                            <div className="modal_grid_3">
                                <div className="modal_grid_item">
                                    <EditableLabel text={this.state.addUserFirstName}
                                        labelClassName='modal_label'
                                        inputClassName='modal_input'
                                        inputWidth='150px'
                                        inputHeight='28px'
                                        inputMaxLength='50'
                                        onFocus={this._handleFocus}
                                        onFocusOut={this._handleFocusOutAddFirstName}
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <div className="modal_grid_item">
                                    <EditableLabel text={this.state.addUserLastName}
                                        labelClassName='modal_label'
                                        inputClassName='modal_input'
                                        inputWidth='150px'
                                        inputHeight='28px'
                                        inputMaxLength='50'
                                        onFocus={this._handleFocus}
                                        onFocusOut={this._handleFocusOutAddLastName}
                                    />
                                </div>
                                 <div className="modal_grid_item">
                                    <Select 
                                    options={options} 
                                    defaultValue={options[0]}
                                    styles={colourStyles}
                                    onChange={this.addUserSelectChange}
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <div className="modal_input_label">
                                    First Name
                                </div>
                                <div className="modal_input_label">
                                    Last Name
                                </div>
                                <div className="modal_input_label">
                                    Role
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="modal_grid_email">

                                <div className="modal_grid_item">
                                    <EditableLabel text={this.state.newUserEmail}
                                        labelClassName='modal_label'
                                        inputClassName='modal_input'
                                        inputWidth='350px'
                                        inputHeight='28px'
                                        inputMaxLength='50'
                                        onFocus={this._handleFocus}
                                        onFocusOut={this.changeAddEmail}
                                    />
                                </div>
                                 <div className="modal_input_label">
                                    Email
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <h5>Set Password</h5>
                            <div className="modal_grid_2 pass_grid">

                                <div className="modal_grid_item">
                                   <input type="password" className="pass_input" onChange={this.newPassSet}/>
                                </div>
                                <div className="modal_grid_item">
                                   <input type="password" className="pass_input" onChange={this.confirmNewPassCheck}/>
                                </div>
                                 <div className="modal_input_label">
                                    Password
                                </div>
                                 <div className="modal_input_label">
                                    Confirm Password
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            {this.state.studentSelected &&
                                <div>
                                    <h5>Assign Instructor</h5>
                                    <div className="modal_grid_1">

                                        <div className="modal_grid_item">
                                            <Select 
                                            options={this.state.instructors} 
                                            defaultValue={this.state.instructors[0]}
                                            styles={colourStyles}
                                            onChange={this.instructorSelectChange}
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="modal_input_label">
                                            Instructor
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            }
                        </div>
                        <div className="modal_button_wrap">
                            <button className="cancel_button" onClick={() => this.closeAddUserModal()}>Cancel</button>
                            <button disabled={this.state.addSaveDisable} className="save_button" onClick={this.addUser}>Save</button>
                            <div className="error_msg">{this.state.addErrors}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Modal>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about this line ? `users: data`
Where's the data comes from ?

```
axios.get('/all-users').then(response => {

        this.setState({ 
          users: data, 
        })
      })
```

Comment: That was a question typo. Its response.data

Comment: You said this `I make some changes through a modal and call the same axios call to update the state`, could you provide the code ?